# Preflight Request throwing an CORS error on AWS API Gateway

Tags: aws-lambda, cors, aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless, preflight

I am learning about nuances of AWS hosting.
I have relatively small app that works well on localhost, and in combination with Postman.

My setup is:

**S3 hosted React app** - with **Cloudfront distribution** in front of it

Serverless **Node js** application (**Lambda**) - with **API Gateway** in front of it

**GET** request works fine.
Initially, i had CORS error there as well, but i managed to get past it.

I cannot get POST to work at all. I will provide several key screenshots, and i am willing to provide more if that will fix the issue.

here is my `serverless.yml`. Note that i have tried all sort of configuration within yml, this is latest state

```
functions:
  api:
    handler: server.handler
    events:
      - httpApi:
          path: /rsb/vote/{voteId}
          method: GET
      - httpApi:
          path: /rsb/vote
          method: POST
          cors:
            origin: '*'
            headers:
              - Content-Type
              - X-Amz-Date
              - Accept
              - Authorization
              - X-Api-Key
              - X-Amz-Security-Token
              - X-Amz-User-Agent
            allowCredentials: false
```

defined routes within `API Gateway`

[Routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5stE.png)

CORS configuration (I masked Cloudfront distribution URL)

[CORS configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkqS4.png)

Followed this tutorial, and also several other that i can find online
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html#apigateway-responding-to-cors-preflight

So, i created Lambda function and attached it to API Gateway route. Note that i have routes for {proxy+} in both root and /rsb namespace, just to be sure

[Lambda function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGwh1.png)

Postman can hit the route correctly

[Postman hitting the API - response body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZvY6.png)

However, i suspect that response headers are not good. And if i understand this correctly, Preflight will hit my API with OPTIONS, to test if url is valid. Despite me specifically writing inside handler what i want to use as header response.

[Postman hitting the API - response headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7JLp.png)

Also relevant, error message from browser, and response headers that are missing `Allow Origin` header
CORS Error (replaced actual URL with dummy)

*Access to fetch at 'apirul' from origin 'cloudfronturl' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.*

[Response headers in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwwAq.png)

What are other configuration options that i should consider?
Should i change Behaviour of Cloudfront distribution?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)